# Magento2, admin-panel Ui Component, xml is missing the target

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, uicomponent, customer-grid

Considering below code, what changes in xml is necessary to make the link recognize the `'target' => '_blank'`?

xml file:

```
 <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <actionsColumn name="login_as_customer" class="vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Login</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
```

Actions.php

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $hidden = !$this->_authorization->isAllowed('vendor_Module::login_button');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        'loginascustomer/login/login',
                        ['customer_id' => $item['entity_id']]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Login As Customer'),
                    'hidden' => $hidden,
                    'target' => '_blank',
                ];
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Both questions are creaed by me. No duplication, here the question is in xml file!

Comment: "POSSIBLE duplication", pls read carefully then make marking decision as it affects getting the problem solved

Comment: To update only XML I think It's not valid to ask a new question. you can update your previous question. that's why this question is under duplication

Comment: They are related to different scenarios, why should I combine them?

Comment: Let's decide community then :)

Comment: @Zinat  Have you found any solution